# http get in vb6 and receive xml data

Tags: xml, vb6, http-get

I don't know much thing in vb6.  I have a problem
I need to make a http get request to a server, and the response will be some xml data. i also have to send some data to server via query string. I'm new to vb6 and don't have any idea about how to do that. need your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is using the DOMDocument class, which should be on all versions of Windows from 2000 to 7. Add a reference to a version of "Microsoft Xml".

```
Dim oDocument As MSXML2.DOMDocument

Set oDocument = New MSXML2.DOMDocument
oDocument.Load "http://xmlserver.domainname?myQueryString"

Do Until oDocument.readyState = 4
    DoEvents
Loop

Parse(oDocument.DocumentElement)
DisplayXml(oDocument.Xml)
```

Comment: Thanks. It gave me a idea of how to do this. I've modified it as per my need. Thanks again. :)